# Transpose of a table using vertica

Tags: sql, vertica

Recently I came across vertica which is a columnar database and I need to transpose the underlying table. That is turn all the columns to rows.

```
+--------+--------+------------+------------+
| emp_no | salary | from_date  | to_date    |
+--------+--------+------------+------------+
|  10001 |  60117 | 1986-06-26 | 1987-06-26 |
|  10001 |  62102 | 1987-06-26 | 1988-06-25 |
|  10001 |  66074 | 1988-06-25 | 1989-06-25 |
|  10001 |  66596 | 1989-06-25 | 1990-06-25 |
|  10001 |  66961 | 1990-06-25 | 1991-06-25 |
|  10001 |  71046 | 1991-06-25 | 1992-06-24 |
|  10001 |  74333 | 1992-06-24 | 1993-06-24 |
|  10001 |  75286 | 1993-06-24 | 1994-06-24 |
|  10001 |  75994 | 1994-06-24 | 1995-06-24 |
|  10001 |  76884 | 1995-06-24 | 1996-06-23 |
|  10001 |  80013 | 1996-06-23 | 1997-06-23 |
|  10001 |  81025 | 1997-06-23 | 1998-06-23 |
|  10001 |  81097 | 1998-06-23 | 1999-06-23 |
|  10001 |  84917 | 1999-06-23 | 2000-06-22 |
|  10001 |  85112 | 2000-06-22 | 2001-06-22 |
|  10001 |  85097 | 2001-06-22 | 2002-06-22 |
|  10001 |  88958 | 2002-06-22 | 9999-01-01 |
|  10002 |  65828 | 1996-08-03 | 1997-08-03 |
|  10002 |  65909 | 1997-08-03 | 1998-08-03 |
|  10002 |  67534 | 1998-08-03 | 1999-08-03 |
|  10002 |  69366 | 1999-08-03 | 2000-08-02 |
|  10002 |  71963 | 2000-08-02 | 2001-08-02 |
|  10002 |  72527 | 2001-08-02 | 9999-01-01 |
|  10003 |  40006 | 1995-12-03 | 1996-12-02 |
|  10003 |  43616 | 1996-12-02 | 1997-12-02 |
|  10003 |  43466 | 1997-12-02 | 1998-12-02 |
|  10003 |  43636 | 1998-12-02 | 1999-12-02 |
|  10003 |  43478 | 1999-12-02 | 2000-12-01 |
|  10003 |  43699 | 2000-12-01 | 2001-12-01 |
|  10003 |  43311 | 2001-12-01 | 9999-01-01 |
+--------+--------+------------+------------+
```

The following points must be noted:

1. One cannot use `case` in this situation.
2. One can use dynamic queries if they want.

The issue that I am facing is that I'm not able to understand how to iteratively turn multiple column entries into rows.

Comment: Please show an example of the results you want.  Why can't `case` be used?  It is definitely part of Vertica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do that. Even if Vertica allows for more columns than other relational databases, namely 1600 instead of Oracle's 1024, for example.

If you have an average of 15 versions per emp_no, you will run out of possible columns with 11 employees.

Can you suggest what kind of data processing you want to do with that afterwards? It's very probable that there are other ways to get all measures together ...